# How to put graphql request result in a variable?

Tags: graphql

I wrote the following code :

```
const { request } = require('graphql-request')
const query = `query{  allData{    Id,    name  }}`  
request('http://......./', query,).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Now, I want to put "data" in a variable instead of writing it by console.log. How should I put this data in a variable for example called "allData"?

I know it is an elementary simple question, but all the examples I found in the web are writing data by console.log and I don't know what is the syntax.

Comment: `request('http://......./', query,).then(allData => console.log(allData))` ?

Answer (score 0):

`graphql-request` is returning a promise, in the `.then` you can name your parameter the way you want.

Maybe you would find `async/await` syntax easier to understand :

```
async function myFunc() {
  const data = await request('http://......./', query);
  const allData = data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.Is there any way to get the result ( I mean "data" ) directly,synchronously without waiting and not as a promise?

Comment: Don't think so.